# Problema en c# con clase declarada pero que no es detectada

Tags: c#, visual-studio

soy nuevo aprendiendo c#, intento hacer un archivo sencillo pero no da un error al no detectar la clase persona.

No se si esta mal ubicada la clase y/o me falta dar "using" a alguna librería en particular.

O debo guardar la clase en otro archivo y darle "using" a esa clase para que pueda ser detectada.

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo completo es el siguiente:

```
 using System;

namespace Prueba1
{
    class Program
    {

        public class Persona
        {
            public string identificacion;
            public string nombres;
            public string apellidos;
            public DateTime FechaNacimiento;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>();
            personas.Add("79658321", "Pedro Estiven", "Gil Barón", new DateTime(1979,
            10, 26));
            personas.Add("41582329", "Ana María", "López Torres", new DateTime(1954, 8, 12));
            personas.Add("84632206", "Eugenio", "Joya Rivera", new DateTime(1984, 5, 17));
            personas.Add("7456977", "Carol Johanna", "Pérez Castro", new DateTime(1975, 2,
            5));
            personas.Add("15608542", "Pablo Raúl", "Téllez Sánchez", new DateTime(1949, 1,
            19));
            string result = ProcesarPersona(personas);
        }

              

        public string ProcesarPersona(List<Persona> personas)
        {
            decimal Resultado1 = 0;
            decimal Resultado2 = 0;
            int valor = 0;
            DateTime fechaActual = new DateTime(2018, 3, 23);
            foreach (Persona p in personas)
            {   
                valor = calcularEdad(p.FechaNacimiento, fechaActual);
                if (valor > Resultado1) { Resultado1 = valor; }
                Resultado2 = Resultado2 + valor;
            }
            Resultado2 = Resultado2 / personas.Length;
            return "Resultado 1:" +Resultado1 + "Resultado 2:" +Resultado2;
        }

        private int calcularEdad(DateTime fechaNacimiento, DateTime fechaActual)
        {
            int edad = DateTime.Today.Year - fechaNacimiento.Year;

            return edad;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema no es la clase persona.. te falta el using para List...

Comment: es mas.. eso en rojo te esta marcando un error.. si pones el error que te marca, es mucho mas facil decirte que pasa

Comment: @gbianchi use el "using List;" pero me salta error diciendo: El nombre de la directiva no es necesario.

Comment: @gbianchi El error que me marca en rojo dice: El nombre de tipo 'list<>' no se encontró

Comment: Porque para usar una lista, no existe using list... mira [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) la documentacion tiene todas las soluciones.. es using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: Y ese error es claramente tu problema.. no la clase persona...

Comment: Use el "using System.Collections.Generic", y ahora me da error de las lìneas 20-26 donde me dice: ninguna sobrecarga para el metodo add toma 4 argumentos

Comment: Si vamos a seguir asi, voy a corregir tu codigo linea por linea, y no.. no tiene sentido... Aprende a aprender.. que es el metodo add?? que dice la documentacion sobre ese metodo? que parametros recibe? tu mejor aliado, es la documentacion, no preguntar linea por linea. Y no.. el metodo add recibe un objeto del tipo que dijiste que tenia la lista.. no un monton de parametros para armar el objeto...

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, el metodo `Add` espera un objeto del tipo especificado, en este caso `Persona`. Puedes hacer algo asi: `personas.Add(new Persona(){identificacion ="79658321",  nombres = "Pedro Estiven", apellidos="Gil Barón", FechaNacimiento=new DateTime(1979,
            10, 26)});`